# Can you add an AppBar(Or something similar) to a SingleChildScrollView?

Tags: flutter

I'm looking to have a fixed row at the top of a SingleChildScrollView, like an AppBar. Is this possible? If so how? Any help is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to scroll your appbar?

Comment: I'd like the "AppBar" to travel down as the user scrolls. So they are aware of what they are looking at in the ScrollView. Kind of like a header. So the "AppBar" won't disappear as the user scrolls down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a Column with 2 Children. A normal `Container` and a `SingleChildScrollView`. You can use the `Expanded` Widget to give Everything a relative height.